# Is the following statement true? "The collection of zero-divisors together with the zero element in a ring forms an ideal in that ring"

Tags: ring-theory

Is the following statement true?
"The collection of zero-divisors together with the zero element in a ring forms an ideal in that ring"

I guess it is false. For a ring $\mathbb Z_{12}$, $$I={\{0,2,6,3,4 }\}$$ is the set of zero-divisors with zero element then $I$ is not an additive subgroup of $\mathbb Z_{12}$ so not an ideal in $\mathbb Z_{12}$.
Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plenty of counter examples.  Consider $2\times2$ matrices.

$$A = \left(\begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}\right)$$

and

$$B = \left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}\right)$$

Their product is $0$ hence they are zero-divisors but their sum is the identity which is not a zero divisor.  So, not even a subgroup under addition.

Comment: In fact, so many counter examples that it might be more interesting to find an example, other than trivial ones, in which it was the case.

Comment: Answering my own additional question, $\Bbb{Z}_4$ is an example though not very exciting.